# Discord.js v13 Reaction Roles

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I already have this code to post an embed and to add a reaction, I'm just wondering how I would go about adding a role to a user when they add the reaction?

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}rr`)) {
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#ffffff")
        .setTitle(" Our Servers Rules ")
        .setDescription("To keep our server safe we need a few basic rules for everyone to follow!")
        .setFooter("Please press ✅ to verify and unlock the rest of the server!")
        .addFields(
            {
                name: "1.",
                value: "Stay friendly and don't be toxic to other users, we strive to keep a safe and helpful environment for all!",
            },
            {
                name: "2.",
                value: "Keep it PG-13, don't use racist, homophobic or generally offensive language/overly explicit language!",
            },
            {
                name: "3.",
                value: "If you want to advertise another server/website etc please contact me first!",
            },
            { name: "4.", value: "Don't cause drama, keep it civil!" },
            {
                name: "5.",
                value: "If you have any questions please contact me @StanLachie#4834",
            }
        );
    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] }).then((sentMessage) => {
        sentMessage.react("✅");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check this [Discord.js Guide page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector). But in summary...

```
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    const role = await message.guild.roles.fetch("role id");
    
    message.guild.members.fetch(user.id).then(member => {
         member.roles.add(role);  
    });
});
```